# Creating Attribute table to calculate fragmentation with FRAGSTAT?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, attribute-table

I created with a LS8 image Buffers with the size of 1/2/3km. For each buffer, which has 3 classes I want to analyize the fragmentation. For that fragstat require a GeoTIFF image with an Attribute table.

My Problem is that I have a GeoTIFF image without an attribute table.

How I can create one?

Comment: You do not need an attribute table, just an integer raster within a specific bit range (at least 4 bit). For good reason, Fragstats will not work on floating point rasters.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an attribute table using "build raster attribute table" in the Data Management toolbox (raster properties). I assume that you have a classification of your LS8 image because you mention 3 classes: this is necessary in order to built a raster attribute table.